# my dc.js graph is not display on my flask application and mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, flask, d3.js, dc.js

I am returning an array of objects from a collection in MongoDB with this function:

````
```
        @app.route('/data')
        def data():
            FIELDS = {'_id': False, 'book_title': True, 'review_rating': True}
        
            projects = mongo.db.reviews.find({}, FIELDS)
            json_projects = []
            for project in projects:
                json_projects.append(project)
            json_projects = json.dumps(json_projects, default=json_util.default)
            return json_projects
    
    ```
````

When I start the server I can see the data are loaded correctly( this is from the console of google developer tool)

````
        (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
        0: {book_title: "Il guardiano degli Innocenti", review_rating: 3}
        1: {book_title: "The Lord of the Ring", review_rating: 3}
        2: {book_title: "Time of Contempt", review_rating: 4}
        length: 3
       
        

then I start making my graph in graph.js with this code:

```    
    queue()
        .defer(d3.json, "/data")
        .await(makeGraphs);
    
    function makeGraphs(error, projectsJson) {
        var ndx = crossfilter(projectsJson);
    
        show_rating_for_title(ndx);
    
        dc.renderAll();
    
    }
    
    function show_rating_for_title(ndx) {
        var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('book_title'));
        var group = dim.group();
    
        dc.barChart('#book-rating')
            .width(400)
            .height(300)
            .margins({ top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50 })
            .dimension(dim)
            .group(group)
            .transitionDuration(500)
            .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
            .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
            .elasticY(true)
            .xAxisLabel('Books title')
    }
    d3.json('/data').then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })

```

This is the HTML:

```    
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/609714b29a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.1/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-5xkNvFVCctXwOszeifE8pzjyDFlHvHDCKIrhwmuSbCtTHqc7IhA6/1tTNYXE8WmYvwP5KFQegCS1QRR4poYgjg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js" integrity="sha512-nlO6OGj6wb0uu/thpSry7qFal63hfhCLExpWxYomYB3tBznqWmKggsDHNHSLjnVaoade9tv/rErN498NSzwBnA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.1.0/dc.min.js" integrity="sha512-lHfUFYGOLmlycQeqF3nxeqIAYf4rdpMCLyp2jbBBR0H+vszlngf7itLg0xDcS8WmO+3TYOcfkQXJXz7rVJ2xbA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/queue-async/1.0.7/queue.min.js" integrity="sha512-Pizidz0hqpLXeVq+TGqNB5KWVynUPVRTt5shjKBbQIklpnCkdmQJ3rCkzGEe713SAnzIsRt/kFTs4jWG/aPmYA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/graph.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Bookland</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="book-rating">
    
    </div>
    </body>
    ```
````

The graph is not loaded and no error are showed on the console. after hours of research is impossible for me to understand why, please give me an hand.

Comment: did you try error handling for the `error` parameter to `makeGraphs`?

Comment: Hi, yes I did but the console doesn't return any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses a mix of d3@3 and d3@5+, and this is probably the root of your problem.

D3@5 changed from callbacks to Promises.

Your final

```
d3.json('/data').then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

will work with d3@5+, and I presume this where you are seeing the correct data returned.

On the other hand, the code that uses `queue()` and your chart initialization code are written to work with d3@3 (and dc@2).

Unfortunately, if you try to use d3@5 with `queue()` then *nothing happens*. As you said in the comments, you don't see an error, but I suspect this code is not being hit at all.

I would recommend removing the `queue()` code and using the working Promise-based `d3.json` code.

At that point you will still need to upgrade your D3 and dc.js code, but this isn't all that hard, mostly rename `d3.scale.linear` to `d3.scaleLinear`, same with ordinal.

- [Changes in d3@4](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-40)
- [Changes in d3@5](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50)
- [dc@3 upgrade guide](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/docs/dc-v3-upgrade-guide.md)
- [dc@4 upgrade guide](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/docs/dc-v4-upgrade-guide.md)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I cancelled the queue code and I updated my dc and d3 and I get a graph indeed!